# How are these case statements types evaluated?

Tags: scala

From http://backchatio.github.io/hookup/scaladoc/io/backchat/hookup/DefaultHookupClient.html have this code :

```
  new DefaultHookupClient(HookupClientConfig(new URI("ws://localhost:8080/thesocket"))) {

    def receive = {
      case Disconnected(_) ⇒ println("The websocket to " + uri.toASCIIString + " disconnected.")
      case TextMessage(message) ⇒ {
        println("RECV: " + message)
        send("ECHO: " + message)
      }
    }

    connect() onSuccess {
      case Success ⇒
        println("The websocket is connected.")
      case _ ⇒
    }
  }
```

`receive` is a callback function that is fired when a connection update is received but how are each of the case statements types determined as there is no match statement, what are the case statements matching against ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Scala's syntactic sugar for defining partial functions and is not specific to `match` (which is its own language construct and not formally a method). This is why you can write the following, for example:

```
scala> Option(1).map { case x if x == 1 => "foo"; case _ => "bar" }
res0: Option[String] = Some(foo)
```

`map` expects a `Function[Int, B]` here for some `B`, and `PartialFunction[Int, String]` is a subtype of `Function[Int, String]`, so we can use the partial function syntactic sugar to provide the argument.

Note that the input and output types of the partial function have to be known—i.e. they can't just be inferred (there's a similar restriction on Scala's ordinary anonymous function syntax):

```
scala> val f = { case x if x == 1 => "foo"; case _ => "bar" }
<console>:11: error: missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: ?
       val f = { case x if x == 1 => "foo"; case _ => "bar" }
               ^
```

In the case you're looking at, `DefaultHookupClient` inherits a `receive` method with the return type `Receive`, which is a type alias for `PartialFunction[InboundMessage, Unit]`, so you don't run into this restriction as the type is already known.

Comment: pattern matching is occuring over Receive type ? 'map expects a Function[Int, B]'  (f: (A) ⇒ B) (taken from http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.Option) is syntactic sugar for Function[Int, B] ?

Comment: @blue-sky Yes, `A => B` is sugar for `Function[A, B]`, and the matched type is `InboundMessage`, since `Receive` is an alias for `PartialFunction[InboundMessage, Unit]`.

Comment: 'DefaultHookupClient inherits a receive method with the return type Receive, which is a type alias for PartialFunction[InboundMessage, Unit]' sorry but this does not make sense to me as it seems your saying 'Receive' is pattern matching over its return type but the return type is not known until method is evaluated or does the inherited 'Receive' method already contain the return type  ? is PartialFunction[InboundMessage, Unit] implicitly passed to 'Receive' method ?

Comment: @blue-sky This is just about the syntax: `{ case whatever => stuff }` can't be used in an arbitrary context—the expected type has to be known. It is known here because we're implementing the supertype's `receive`.

Comment: is receive method being overriden in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

They are matching against the function parameter. It's a shortcut you can use with anonymous functions:

```
 { 
     case foo => bar
     case bat => baz
 }
```

is the same as

```
{ x => x match {
    case foo => bar
    case bat => baz
}}
```